# Build breaking after bazel upgrade

Tags: bazel

I recently upgraded bazel to `0.25.2`. (Forgot from which version but in the low 0.20's)

But since upgrade my bazel build of buchgr/bazel-remote fails with the following errors:

```
ERROR: /Users/<user>/Workspace/bazel-remote-cache/WORKSPACE:1:1: name 'http_archive' is not defined
ERROR: /Users/<user>/Workspace/bazel-remote-cache/WORKSPACE:9:1: name 'http_archive' is not defined
ERROR: /Users/<user>/Workspace/bazel-remote-cache/WORKSPACE:15:1: name 'git_repository' is not defined
ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'go/image.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_docker//go': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'go/image.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_docker//go': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.068s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Not sure why this is happening? I don't see any documentation which says `http_archive` or `git_repository` is deprecated. I am new to bazel, can someone help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http_archive` was marked as deprecated in Bazel version 0.20.0 to 0.17.1 (take a look on the Bazel documentation for more information)

Assuming that you are using Bazel 0.25.0: Add to your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
```

Take a look at the [Backward Compatibility](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.25.0/backward-compatibility.html) site of Bazel:

> Bazel is evolving, and we will make changes to Bazel that at times
>   will be incompatible and require some changes from Bazel users.

To prevent you from such errors in the future document your used Bazel version in the source code - add for instance this to your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "check_bazel_version")

check_bazel_version("0.23.1")
```

Comment: Add a hint for coming people who just found this answer. Currently, the .deb on the official site no longer provides old version. the old version can get from here github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tags?after=0.19.0